# jQuery functions retrieving and passing data

Tags: jquery

If I have a function in jQuery that holds some values:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myFunction = function() {
        var option1 = 'green';
        var option2 = 'green';
        var option3 = 'green';
        return option1, option2, option3;
    }

    $.fn.myFunction2 = function(option1, option2, option3) {
    }
}) (jQuery);
```

If I wanted to pass the data from `myFunction` to `myFunction2`, how do I achieve it? And if I was to call the script in the following manner `var data = $('div').myFunction();` how do I get access to each `option`?

Reading through a few books on the subject but its not being explained that well.

EDIT:

I would want to use the returned data in the following way:

```
var options = $('article').myFunction(); 
$('article').myFunction2(options);
```

but I would also like to be able to pull out individual items

```
var options = $('article').myFunction();
$('article').myFunction2(options[option2]);
```

Comment: First, `return option1, option2, option3;` is effectively the same as `return option3;`. You have to describe your problem better. For example, how/where do you want to call `myFunction2`?

Comment: how do you return multiple values that can then be used elsewhere?

Comment: By either returning an array or object. Btw, you should only extend `$.fn` if you are planning to work with the selected elements (e.g. the `div`s). If you don't want to manipulate DOM elements with these functions, just create normal functions.

Comment: I don't understand why you extend jQuery for that. Are you doing anything with the selected `article` elements (for example)?

Comment: Yes I am, I can't really put all the code in here but its todo with responsive web design based on a scalable block grid.

Comment: Ok. Depending on what kind of options these are, you might want to consider using objects, e.g. `{option1: 'green', option2: 'green'}`, pass such an object to `myFunction2` and access the properties you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array to pass the data.

```
(function ($) {

  $.fn.myFunction = function() {

    var option1 = 'green';
    var option2 = 'green';
    var option3 = 'green';

    return [option1, option2, option3];
  }

 $.fn.myFunction2 = function(options) {

 }

}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: I understand I could access the data in the following way `console.log(data[2]);` but how can I access it by name, like this for example `console.log(data[option2]);`?

Comment: @CraigWard If you want access by name, use the object literal, and then access by `data["option2"]` or `data.option2`.

Comment: @Craig: There are other ways, but you don't provide enough information. Again, how/where do you intend to call `myFunction2`? Do you want to call it from `myFunction`?